# Reverse score a subset of items based on variable predefined maximums

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply, stringr

**I have longitudinal data for which I would like to reverse score a subset of items using corresponding predefined maximum scores that are stored in a seperate data frame.**

In the below example data (`df`) there are three scores, DST, SOS, and VR at two timepoints (baseline and wave 1). `neg_skew.vars` contains the scores that are to be reverse across timepoints. I would like to reverse scores based on the maximum possible value for that score, as stored in `df.CP1.vars$max.vars`. **I'd like this to work when multiple scores with different maximum values are included in** `neg_skew.vars`.

**For example**, in the example below "SOS.score" is stored in `neg_skew.vars`. Therefore I want all SOS.Score variables to be reversed (i.e., across timepoints); this would include 'SOS.Score.baseline' and 'SOS.Score.wave1' in the example data below. I want scores to be reversed using the corresponding maximum score for SOS. For each SOS variable, I want each value to be reversed like this: *(20 + 1) - value*. The 20 corresponds to the maximum value for SOS stored in `df.CP1.vars`. As DST is also negatively skewed, all DST scores (i.e., 'DST.Score.baseline' and 'DST.Score.wave1') should be reveresed, but with 16 as the maximum value, per `df.CP1.vars`, so: *(16 + 1) - value*. This results in the desired data frame `df_wanted` below. VR.Score does not appear in `neg_skew.vars` and so no VR.Score variables are reversed (i.e., VR.Score.baseline and VR.Score.wave1).

So far I have the code listed below under `# reverse scores` however this produces two undesired outcomes in the resulting data frame (i.e., `df2`). These are A) the columns for other scores, such as DST, are not retained, and B) the maximum value used to reverse items is the maximum value for that item/at that timepoint; this is a problem as the data is longitudinal.

**The desired data should look like `df_wanted`. I tried to set up a for-loop but ran into problems with using the dplyr pipeline.**

```
# required packages
library(dplyr)

# create relevant variables and data sets
CP1.vars <- c("DST.Score","SOS.Score", "VR.Score")
max.vars <- c(16,20,80)
df.CP1.vars <- data.frame(CP1.vars, max.vars)

df <- structure(list(
  SOS.Score.baseline = c(4, 11, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9, 10), 
  SOS.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 7.5, 8.5, NA, NA, 6.66, NA, 6, 8, 8, 7, 8), 
  DST.Score.baseline = c(11, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6), 
  DST.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 10, 8.5, NA, NA, 8, NA, 9.33, 9, 7, 8, 8), 
  VR.Score.baseline = c(NA, 60, 38.5, 50, NA, 48, NA, 33, 49, 67, 78, 80), 
  VR.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 58, 38.5, NA, NA, 40, NA, 35, 49, 67, 78, 78)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

neg_skew.vars <- c("SOS.Score", "DST.Score")

# reverse scores
df2 <- df %>% 
  select(contains(neg_skew.vars)) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE) + 1 - . , .names = "{.col}_r"))

# desired outcome (order of variables irrelevant)
df_wanted <- structure(list(
  SOS.Score.baseline = c(4, 11, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9, 10), 
  SOS.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 7.5, 8.5, NA, NA, 6.66, NA, 6, 8, 8, 7, 8), 
  SOS.Score.baseline_r = c(17, 10, 14, 12, 11, 13, 15, 13, 14, 21, 12, 11), 
  SOS.Score.wave1_r = c(NA, 13.5, 12.5, NA, NA, 14.34, NA, 15, 13, 13, 14, 13), 
  DST.Score.baseline = c(11, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6), 
  DST.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 10, 8.5, NA, NA, 8, NA, 9.33, 9,  7, 8, 8),
  DST.Score.baseline_r = c(6, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 10, 11, 10, 11), 
  DST.Score.wave1_r = c(NA, 7, 8.5, NA, NA, 9, NA, 7.67, 8, 10, 9, 9),
  VR.Score.baseline = c(NA, 60, 38.5, 50, NA, 48, NA, 33, 49, 67, 78, 80), 
  VR.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 58, 38.5, NA, NA, 40, NA, 35, 49, 67, 78, 78)),
  row.names = c(NA,12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about this part? "I would like to reverse scores based on the maximum possible value for that score, as stored in df.CP1.vars$max.vars".  Maybe you can walk through an example of what that looks like.

Comment: I've update the question @JonSpring - hope this helps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map_dfc` to loop over the `neg_skew.vars` and get the value directly from `df.CP1.vars`, and then `bind` the resulting dataframe with columns that remained unchanged.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

df2 <- neg_skew.vars %>% 
  map_dfc(function(a) df %>% 
        select(matches(a)) %>%
        mutate(across(everything(), ~ df.CP1.vars$max.vars[df.CP1.vars$CP1.vars == a] + 1 - .,
               .names = "{.col}_r"))) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% 
              select(!contains(neg_skew.vars)))
```

This indeed leads to the desired outcome:

```r
identical(df2, df_wanted)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Data:

```r
# create relevant variables and data sets
CP1.vars <- c("DST.Score","SOS.Score", "VR.Score")
max.vars <- c(16,20,80)
df.CP1.vars <- data.frame(CP1.vars, max.vars)

df <- structure(list(
  SOS.Score.baseline = c(4, 11, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 8, 7, 0, 9, 10), 
  SOS.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 7.5, 8.5, NA, NA, 6.66, NA, 6, 8, 8, 7, 8), 
  DST.Score.baseline = c(11, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6), 
  DST.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 10, 8.5, NA, NA, 8, NA, 9.33, 9, 7, 8, 8), 
  VR.Score.baseline = c(NA, 60, 38.5, 50, NA, 48, NA, 33, 49, 67, 78, 80), 
  VR.Score.wave1 = c(NA, 58, 38.5, NA, NA, 40, NA, 35, 49, 67, 78, 78)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

neg_skew.vars <- c("SOS.Score", "DST.Score")
```

Comment: Thanks @Maël - completely my fault, the questions was not entirely clear. I'd like the code to work when multiple scores with different maximum values are included in neg_skew.vars. Question has been updated to make this more clear.

Comment: See edit. You can use iterate over the vector with `purrr::map`.

Comment: I'm getting this error when running the above edited code: Error: unexpected input in:
"df2 <- neg_skew.vars %>% 
  map_dfc(\"

Comment: I added the complete code so that you can reproduce the code. Tell me if the error persists.

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting the same error. In case relevant, I also get this error (but perhaps this is because of the first error): Error: unexpected ')' in:
"            mutate(across(everything(), ~ df.CP1.vars$max.vars[df.CP1.vars$CP1.vars == a] + 1 - .,
                          .names = "{.col}_r")))"

Comment: Oh I see now; this is because \ is a new base R function. Try again with `function` instead of \ (or update R).